# GoogleMaps break business logic Unit Tests

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, unit-testing

I'm writing an iOS app, that uses GoogleMaps. I've written some unit tests to test separate business logic modules. They look like this:

```
func testIfStationsExistNearPoint1() {
        let comMangager = CommunicationManager()
        comMangager.getListOfStations(coordinates: Coordinates(longitude: Constants.Point1CoordinateLongitude, latitude: Constants.Point1CoordinateLatitude), distance: 50, completion: { (json) in
            if (json != nil) {
                let stations = StationWrapper.sharedStationWrapper.jsonToStations(json: json!)

                assert(stations.count > 0, String(format:"%ld stations", stations.count))
            }
            else {
                XCTFail("json is nil")
            }
        }) { (error) in
            XCTFail(String(format:"List of stations returned error: %@", error))
        }
    }
```

Note, that those unit tests are completely separated from UI (Where GoogleMaps are used. Coordinates is a custom class, not GoogleMaps CLLocationCoordinate2D).

Also note, that application itself works ok. And I'm 100% sure, that in main app, all code, that works with map drawing, is called in main thread.

Yet somehow I receive this error, when trying *any* of my unit tests:

> com.google.Maps.LabelingBehavior (15): -[UIApplication
>   applicationState] must be used from main thread only

When I set a breakpoint in the very first line of this unit test, it's not even hit. Same thing for both simulator and real device.

I wonder, how's that even possible, since I'm not using Google Maps anywhere in unit tests? I've tried to search for similar cases, yet haven't found any, that was related unit testing.

Any ideas what's wrong here because I feel completely stuck?

Answer (score 0):

XCode launches your application before executing unit tests.

So this error is produced by your application before Xcode starts executing unit tests. That's why your breakpoint at the beginning of test is not hit.

Placing exception breakpoint should lead you to source of the issue.

Comment: Hmm, you seem to be right... However that doesn't help me. The error itself is somewhere inside google's framework (I've double checked, that I didn't mess with threads anywhere), I can skip it in app (it doesn't affect anything), but I can't skip it in unit tests.